# URLDownloadToFile downloads file, file saves but is corrupt

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I’m trying to use `VBA` to save an online pdf. The macro goes to a website, logs in, enters several inputs and then generates a pdf. The pdf opens in a new tab. I’ve been using URLDownloadToFile to save the pdf. I can get the pdf to save, however, when I try and open it, I get this message: Acrobat could not open ‘pdfname.pdf’ because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn’t correctly decoded). I can’t share the links because it’s an intranet site.

I think the problem is, since the pdf opens in a new tab, the fact that I’m logged in is not recognized and that’s why the pdf is corrupted. Is there a way to put in a username and password using URLDownloadToFile?

I’ve tried ideas from other posts such as putting the credentials in the url using https://username:password@link.pdf but that didn’t work. I performed a network trace to find other urls but the other links didn't work either. I also cleared the cache and when I check the status of the url I get "200 - OK" but I still save a corrupted file.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "wininet" Alias _
    "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" (ByVal lpszUrlName As String) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
"URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
ByVal szURL As String, _
ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
Private Declare Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "wininet" Alias _
    "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" (ByVal lpszUrlName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
"URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, _
ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#End If

Public PageSource As String
Public httpRequest As Object

Function GetURLStatus(ByVal URL As String, Optional AllowRedirects As Boolean)
Const WinHttpRequestOption_UserAgentString = 0
Const WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects = 6

On Error Resume Next
Set httpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
If httpRequest Is Nothing Then
    Set httpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5")
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

httpRequest.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_UserAgentString) = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
httpRequest.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = AllowRedirects

'Clear any pervious web page source information
PageSource = ""

'Add protocol if missing
If InStr(1, URL, "://") = 0 Then
    URL = "http://" & URL
End If

'Launch the HTTP httpRequest synchronously
On Error Resume Next
httpRequest.Open "GET", URL, False
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  'Handle connection errors
    GetURLStatus = Err.Description
    Err.Clear
    Exit Function
End If
On Error GoTo 0

'Send the http httpRequest for server status
On Error Resume Next
httpRequest.Send
httpRequest.WaitForResponse
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  ' Handle server errors
    PageSource = "Error"
    GetURLStatus = Err.Description
    Err.Clear
Else
  'Show HTTP response info
    GetURLStatus = httpRequest.Status & " - " & httpRequest.StatusText
  'Save the web page text
    PageSource = httpRequest.responsetext
End If
On Error GoTo 0
End Function

sub macro()
'some code to generate pdf

    Dim strDest As String
    Dim strSource As String
    strSource = "https://url.pdf"
    strDest = "dir/folder/folder/pdfname.pdf"

    'CLEAR CACHE
    DeleteUrlCacheEntry (strSource)

    'CHECK URL
    Debug.Print GetURLStatus(strSource, True)

    'SAVE PDF
    URLDownloadToFile 0, strSource, strDest, 0, 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try opening the downloaded file in a text editor (or notepad) and see if there are any clues in there?  How large is the downloaded file?

Comment: If I try to save it as a .txt file, I get a text file with the html for the login page. Usually the files are about 200-250 KB.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. If you open up Adobe. You can go to Edit->Preferences->Internet. I then unchecked the box that says "Display PDF in browser". This way the PDF just generated in Adobe and was a lot easier to work with.